# Laravel Problem with Blade syntax and normal html-tags

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

im trying to do a little project with laravel 7 and have a question about creating and updating user roles.

Code in AdminUsersController.php:

```
public function create()
{
  $roles = \App\Role::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
  return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
  $user = User::findOrFail($id);
  $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
  return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user', 'roles'));
}

public function update(UpdateUsersRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = \App\User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($input);
    Session::flash('message', 'User successfully updated.');
    return redirect(route('admin.users.index'));
}
```

Now if im using this blade-syntax in the view form for create and updating this works:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role:') !!}
          {!! Form::select('role_id', array('' => 'Choose Options') + $roles, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But how can i do this without blade syntax? Is there a posibilty to pass the same array in the select tag?
i tried to loop through the $roles but didnt work:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select>
  @foreach($roles as $role)
   <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{role->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
 </select>
</div>
```

i mean i have a solution but i would like to if there is another option without blade syntax..

hope you can help me thank u :)

Comment: `{{role->name}}` should be `{{$role->name}}`. Why no blade syntax?

Comment: im sorry i misstyped.. but this was not the problem, i get this: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object", i would like to know why and if there is another solution than blade syntax

Comment: Make sure that the roles object is not null, use var_dump($roles) to do that.

Comment: Make sure that the roles object is not null, use var_dump($roles) to do that.

Comment: i cannot understand what you mean.. if i var_dump($roles)  =>                       @foreach($roles as $role)
               <option value="">{{var_dump($roles)}}</option>
@endforeach                   it returns an array with 3 rows from my database but if i want to change the role, it wont take it, it is the same as before

Comment: Justo to notice that this is blade syntax too `{{$role->id}}`